# Arduino stops/block after sending a few sms

Tags: arduino

I try to make a script for arduino that has to enter a site where if there is information, arduino has to take it and send it by sms to certain people.
At the moment the script works, but after a certain period it crashes (approximately 24 hours), I tried to reset the variables, to increase the time for checking the information and sending the sms but without success.

I mention, if I reset the arduino, the sms start sending, which makes me think that somewhere it loads its memory and remains stuck, but I don't know the language for arduino so well, what do you suggest me to solve this problem?

This is the code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <TextFinder.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial smsSerial(7, 8);

byte mac[] = {  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02 };
char serverName[] = "www.site.ro";
String location = "/sms/smsTrimise.php HTTP/1.1";

EthernetClient client;
TextFinder  finder( client );

String urlUpdate = "";
String trimiteSMS = "";

long idSMS;
long nrTelefon;
long codActivare;
long codResetare;
int ziProgramare;
int lunaProgramare;
int anProgramare;
int oraStart;
int minuteStart;
int artist;

void setup() {
  smsSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  delay(30000);
  urlUpdate = "";
  trimiteSMS = "";
  senddata();
}

void senddata() {
  if (client.connect(serverName, 80)) {
    
    client.println("GET /sms/smsTrimise.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.site.ro");
    client.println();
    
    if ( finder.find("tipSms=")) {
    
      int tipMesaj = finder.getValue();
      
      if ( finder.find("idSms=")) {
        idSMS = finder.getValue();
      }
      if ( finder.find("telefon=")) {
        nrTelefon = finder.getValue();
      }

      switch (tipMesaj){
        
        case 1:
          if ( finder.find("codActivare=")) {
            codActivare = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Codul de activare este ");
          smsSerial.print(codActivare);
          smsSerial.print(" pentru contul configurat pe www.site.ro");
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          break;
          
        case 2:
          if ( finder.find("codResetare=")) {
            codResetare = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Intra pe link-ul de mai jos pentru resetarea parolei: www.site.ro/reset.php?hash=");
          smsSerial.print(codResetare);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          break;
          
        case 3:
          if ( finder.find("artist=")) {
            artist = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Programarea facuta pe www.site.ro a fost inregistrata si este in curs de aprobare.");
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          anuntaAdmin(artist);
          delay(3000);
          break;
          
        case 4:
          if ( finder.find("ziProgramare=")) {
            ziProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("lunaProgramare=")) {
            lunaProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("anProgramare=")) {
            anProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Programarea din ");
          smsSerial.print(ziProgramare);
          smsSerial.print("-");
          smsSerial.print(lunaProgramare);
          smsSerial.print("-");
          smsSerial.print(anProgramare);
          smsSerial.print(" de pe www.site.ro a fost aprobata. Intra in contul de pe site pentru a vedea toate programarile tale.");
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          break;
          
        case 5:
          if ( finder.find("ziProgramare=")) {
            ziProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("lunaProgramare=")) {
            lunaProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("anProgramare=")) {
            anProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("oraStart=")) {
            oraStart = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("minuteStart=")) {
            minuteStart = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("artist=")) {
            artist = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Iti reamintesc ca peste doua zile, pe data de ");
          smsSerial.print(ziProgramare);
          smsSerial.print("-");
          smsSerial.print(lunaProgramare);
          smsSerial.print("-");
          smsSerial.print(anProgramare);
          smsSerial.print(" la ora ");
          smsSerial.print(oraStart);
          smsSerial.print(":");
          smsSerial.print(minuteStart);
          if (artist == 1) {
            smsSerial.print("0, ai o programare la Stie Name");
          }
          if (artist == 2) {
            smsSerial.print("0, ai o programare la Stie Name");
          }
          if (artist == 3) {
            smsSerial.print("0, ai o programare la Stie Name");
          }
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          break;

        case 6:
          if ( finder.find("ziProgramare=")) {
            ziProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("lunaProgramare=")) {
            lunaProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("anProgramare=")) {
            anProgramare = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("artist=")) {
            artist = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Programarea din ");
          smsSerial.print(ziProgramare);
          smsSerial.print("-");
          smsSerial.print(lunaProgramare);
          smsSerial.print("-");
          smsSerial.print(anProgramare);
          if (artist == 1) {
            smsSerial.print(" la Stie Name a fost anulata. Contateaza-ne pentru mai multe informatii pe - sau 0761000000.");
          }
          if (artist == 2) {
            smsSerial.print(" la Stie Name a fost anulata. Contateaza-ne pentru mai multe informatii pe - sau 072000000.");
          }
          if (artist == 3) {
            smsSerial.print(" la Stie Name a fost anulata. Contateaza-ne pentru mai multe informatii pe - sau 074000000.");
          }
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          anuntaAdminAnulareProgramare(artist);
          break;
          
        case 7:
          if ( finder.find("oraStart=")) {
            oraStart = finder.getValue();
          }
          if ( finder.find("minuteStart=")) {
            minuteStart = finder.getValue();
          }
          update();
          smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(3000);
          trimiteSMS = "AT+CMGS=\"+40";
          trimiteSMS += nrTelefon;
          trimiteSMS += "\"\r";
          smsSerial.println(trimiteSMS);
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.print("Maine la ora ");
          smsSerial.print(oraStart);
          smsSerial.print(":");
          smsSerial.print(minuteStart);
          smsSerial.print("0 ne vedem la Stie Name");
          delay(2000);
          smsSerial.write(26);
          delay(3000);
          break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Eroare conexiune");
  }
  client.stop();
}

void update() {
  urlUpdate = "GET /sms/smsTrimise.php?updateSMS=1&idSMS=";
  urlUpdate += idSMS;
  urlUpdate += " HTTP/1.1";
  client.println(urlUpdate);
  client.println("Host: www.site.ro");
  client.println();
  delay(3000);
}

void anuntaAdmin(int artist) {
  if (artist == 1) {
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(3000);
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+4076000000\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.print("O programare a fost inregistrata pe site (www.site.ro)");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.write(26);
    delay(3000);
  }
  if (artist == 2) {
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(3000);
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+4072000000\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.print("O programare a fost inregistrata pe site (www.site.ro)");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.write(26);
    delay(3000);
  }
  if (artist == 3) {
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(3000);
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+4074000000\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.print("O programare a fost inregistrata pe site (www.site.ro)");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.write(26);
    delay(3000);
  }
}

void anuntaAdminAnulareProgramare(int artist) {
  if (artist == 1) {
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(3000);
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+4076000000\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.print("Programarea din ");
    smsSerial.print(ziProgramare);
    smsSerial.print("-");
    smsSerial.print(lunaProgramare);
    smsSerial.print("-");
    smsSerial.print(anProgramare);
    smsSerial.print(" a fost anulata.");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.write(26);
    delay(3000);
  }
  if (artist == 2) {
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(3000);
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+4072000000\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.print("Programarea din ");
    smsSerial.print(ziProgramare);
    smsSerial.print("-");
    smsSerial.print(lunaProgramare);
    smsSerial.print("-");
    smsSerial.print(anProgramare);
    smsSerial.print(" a fost anulata.");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.write(26);
    delay(3000);
  }
  if (artist == 3) {
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    delay(3000);
    smsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+4074000000\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.print("Programarea din ");
    smsSerial.print(ziProgramare);
    smsSerial.print("-");
    smsSerial.print(lunaProgramare);
    smsSerial.print("-");
    smsSerial.print(anProgramare);
    smsSerial.print(" a fost anulata.");
    delay(2000);
    smsSerial.write(26);
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are likely has heap fragmentation caused by the improper use of String. Move `String urlUpdate` and `String trimiteSMS` into the functions where you use them, there is no reason for it to be as a global variable. BTW, many parts of your code are very similar or same, you should factor them out to a function rather than repeating the same code over and over again.

Comment: See my [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75758/40646) regarding fragmentation and [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85157/using-string-instead-of-c-string-yet-another-attempt-to-touch-a-loaded-issue/85170#85170) to understand more about String.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a piece of code to Arduino blinked with LED. This will show you what's going wrong: if the led still blinking but the board is not sending SMS that means Arduino's memory is ok and you need to check your GSM module. Else you will need to optimize your code because some buffer fills RAM and Arduino stops working.
I see your code uses lots of strings that are eating operating memory. You can bring them into flash using:

```
smsSerial.print(F("Some text here"));
```

Using this simple " F() " macro you can save a lot of RAM.

---

You said: I can reboot Arduino to get it to work again.
So if optimizing code doesn't brings results, you just can softwarely reboot Arduino every 10 hours using " millis() " timer:

```
if(millis() > 36000000){     //If time from start > 36000000 miliseconds
   asm volatile ("jmp 0");   //Softwarely reboot Arduino
}
```

You should paste this if condition to " loop() " cycle of the sketch to Arduino automatically reboot every 10 hours.